# Set item in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have one EditText, Button and ListView. I would like to do after Button is clicked put text from EditText into my ListView like first item. Next click like second item... How can  I do that? Here is My code:

```
zadatSumu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zadatSumu);
nastavit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nastavitBtn);
zoznam = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

   nastavit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                ???
            }
        });
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you reach your goal

Comment: I used shylendrs answer sorry. I dont have enough reputation to vote up :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your class should extends ListActivity and add these fields :

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

//DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LISTVIEW
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

In onCreate get adapter instance:

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

In onClick insert this code:

```
listItems.add(zadatSumu.getText.tostring());
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

set this code for call listview item.

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This will help you dude

### create one separate bean class

### Editvalue.java

```
public class Editvalue implements serializable
{
String strEditvalue="";

public String getstrEditvalue() {
        return strEditvalue;
    }

  public void setstrEditvalue(String stredit) {
       this.strEditvalue = stredit;
    }

}
```

### your activity.java

```
zadatSumu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zadatSumu);
nastavit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nastavitBtn);
zoznam = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
Arraylist<Editvalue> arlistdata=new ArrayList<Editvalue>();
   nastavit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                String streditvalue=zadatSumu.getText().tostring();
Editvalue ed=new Editvalue();
ed.setstrEditvalue(setstrEditvalue);
                arlistdata.add(ed);
 Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
ListAdapter  adapter=new ListAdapter(Youractivity.this,arlistdata);
zoznam.setadapter(adapter);  
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
            }
        });
```

### Listadapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Editvalue> {

ArrayList<Editvalue>ed;
Context context;
LayoutInflator layoutinflator;

public ListAdapter(Context context,List<Editvalue> edval) {
   this.context=context;
this.ed=(ArrayList<Editvalue>)edval;
layoutinflator=LayoutInflator.from(this.context);
}

public int getconut()
{
return ed.size();
}

@Override
public Edvalue getItem(int position)
{
return ed.get(position);
}


@Override
pubic long getItemId(int arg0)
{
return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View convertView = layoutinflator.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);

  try{
final Viewholder holder;
holder=new Viewholder();
holder.txtEdtvalue=(TextView)convertView findViewById(R.id.textview1);
convertView.setTag(holder);

Editvalue edv=new Editvalue();
holder.txtEdtvalue.setText(edv.getstrEditvalue);
     }
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printstacktrace();
}
    return convertView ;   
    }

   class Viewholder{
TextView txtEdtvalue=null;
} 

}
```

### create itemlistrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_type1_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text goes here" />

</LinearLayout>
```

once you complete Let me inform